# how to use throws Exception?

Tags: java, exception

this is my class Person() method inputPersonInfo():

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input Information of Person");
        System.out.println("Please input name");
        name = checkInputString();
        System.out.println("Please input address");
        address = checkInputString();
        System.out.println("Please input salary");
        salary = checkInputSalary();        
        return new Person(name,address,salary);
        
        }
```

this is my check for input method:

```
    public static String checkInputString() {
       //loop until user input true value
        while (true) {
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if (s.isEmpty()) {
                System.err.println("Not empty.");
            } else {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    // check if salary is smaller than 0
    public static double checkInputSalary() {
       //loop until user input true value        
        while (true) {
            try {
                double salary = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
                if (salary < 0) {
                    System.err.println("Salary is greater than zero");
                    System.out.print("Please input salary: ");
                } else {
                    return salary;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.err.println("You must input digidt.");
                System.out.print("Please input salary: ");
            }
        }
    }
```

how can i throws Exception in this method without using the above checkinput method() ?

```
public Person inputPersonInfo (String name, String address, Double salary) throws Exception {}
```

this is my main class(), do i need to throw any Exception in my main class ?:

```
        
        System.out.println("=====Management Person programer=====");        
        
        //call constructor Person
        Person p = new Person(); 
        //enter 3 person 
        for (int i =0; i< 3 ;i++){           
           persons[i] = p.inputPersonInfo(p.getName(), p.getAddress(), p.getSalary());
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: @tgdavies i use the checkinputSalary() method to check if String salary is not a double, 
smaller than 0, it will print the "error" and loop until user input is correct, then i call it in the inputPersonInfo(String String Double) to check, but now my teacher require me to use inputPersonInfo(String String Double) throws Exception{} so i cannot use the outside method anymore

Answer (score 1):

**For unchecked exception:**

`NumberFormatException` is a `RuntimeException`, which is an "unchecked exception", that means even if you don't `try...catch` it, it will eventually thrown to the outside (the caller).

In the outside (the caller), you can `try...catch` it if you want so, or you can ignore it. If the exception happens, it will be thrown out. If your program is a console program, it will be thrown and displays in the console window.

That also means your `main` method don't have to explicitly `try..catch` or `throws` it, and the compiler will still compile it successfully.

**For checked exception:**

On the other side, about the "checked exception", you have to `try..catch` or else the compiler will show you errors. If you do not want to `try...catch` the exception in the current method, you can use `throws Exception` in the method signature. For e.g with `IOException`:

```
public Person inputPersonInfo (String name, String address, Double salary) throws IOException {}
```

In your `main` method that is calling the above `inputPersonInfo()`, you have to `try..catch` or `throws` it in the main method signature.

For e.g: with IOException (a checked exception)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ...
    inputPersonInfo(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: tôi nói tiếng việt để dễ hiểu hơn, vật nếu không dùng cái try...catch thì  nó chỉ lặp lại 1 lần hay là có thể lặp lại được nhiều lần ?

Comment: Lặp lại nhiều lần được nhé. Trừ khi nó bị `try...catch`, còn không cứ `throws` liên tục ra ngoài, ngay cả thằng `main` cũng `throws` ra được, khi đấy Exception sẽ được hiện lỗi ra console.

Comment: English for my above comment (Sorry, I can't edit it after 5mins):
Yes, we can throw the exception from method to method, until we want to `try...catch` it, and even we don't want to catch it, we can throw it outside of `main` method too.

Answer (score 1):

`throws Exception` is used when defining a method to signal that this method may throw an error in case something does not go right. It is simply a signal, it does not handle anything.

In case you add this to a method declaration, wherever you call this method, you will be required (by the IDE, compiler..) to add handling mechanisms, such as a try-catch clause, or add yet another `throws Exception` to the declaration of the method that is calling your "dangerous" method.

Example:

```java
public void dangerousMethod() throws Exception, RuntimeException // Or whatever other exception
{
    throw new Exception("FAKE BUT DANGEROUS");
}
```

```java
public void anotherMethod()
{
    dangerousMethod(); // <------------ Compiler, IDE will complain that this should be handled in some way
    
    
    // Either add try catch:
    
    try
    {
        dangerousMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception e) // Or whatever specific Exception you have
    {
        // Handle it...
    }
    
    
    // Or add the throws Exception at the head of the anotherMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the method so that Exceptions won't be thrown to begin with:

```
public double getSalaryFromUser() {
    String salary = "";
    while (salary.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a Salary amount: --> ");
        salary = in.nextLine();
        /* Input Validation:
           The RegEx below used as argument for  the String#matches() 
           method checks to see if the supplied string is a unsigned
           Integer or floating point numerical value. If anything other 
           than that is supplied then the error message is displayed. 
           The second condition checks to see if the value is greater 
           than 0.9d             */ 
        if (!salary.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") || Double.valueOf(salary) < 1.0d) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry (" + salary + ")! You must supply a");
            System.out.println("numerical value and it must be greater than zero.");
            System.out.println("Try again...");
            System.out.println();
            salary = "";
        }
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(salary);
}
```